# How to add custom error message notification in login page

Tags: http, error-handling, react-admin

I have started integrating the react-admin page, In the login page, I'm trying to manage the error message in the auth provider. I'm not able to get the error message to display in the notification .any one please help.

````
login: ({ username, password }) => {
        const request = { 'email': username, 'password': password}
        return axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_URL+`/login`, request).then(response => {
            let result = response.data;
            
            if(result.success){

            } else {
                console.log(response.data);
                throw new HttpError(result.message);

            }
           // localStorage.setItem('username', username);
            return Promise.resolve();
        }).catch(error => {
            return error;
        });```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useNotify function from react-admin to render custom notifications.

```
//Import the notification
`import {useNotify} from 'react-admin';`
...
...
//Place this line in your component.
`const notify = useNotify();`
...
...
//Place this wherever you want to show notification
`notify('Message of Notification');`
//For error notifications
`notify('Error Notification','error);`
```

More on https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html

Edit: on reading the comment realised that this requires custom error messages.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.8/Translation.html

You would need to replace the messages from 'ra-language-english' with your own.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';

const englishCustomMessages = englishMessages;
englishCustomMessages.ra.auth.sign_in_error = 'Your Custom Message goes here';

const messages = {
    en: englishCustomMessages,
}
const i18nProvider = locale => messages[locale];

const App = () => (
    <Admin locale="en" i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

If you want to customize more notifications look at this file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marmelab/react-admin/89ac783fd9f961401d1c2e8d4ca4965053ed1d21/packages/ra-language-english/index.js

Don't import directly as you may not stay updated with the changes in react-admin. Always override only the required changes.

Comment: I tried this , But got an error Line 9:24:  React Hook "useNotify" is called in function "login" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: @Thei I have edited my reply for the same. No need to use a notification as react-admin already handles that, just customize the messages.